# SQLite NullPointerException error on connection creation

Tags: java, sqlite, jsp, glassfish

I am getting a NullPointerException in this code:

update.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="com.solly.CaliforniaWaterDataVisualizationJSPCode" %>
<title>Updating database</title>
<a href="index.html">Return to home page</a>
<br>
Updating database...<br>
<pre>
<%
CaliforniaWaterDataVisualizationJSPCode.update(request, out);
%>
</pre>
```

CaliforniaWaterDataVisualizationJSPCode.java:

```
package com.solly;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;

import com.solly.parser.PSVParser;

public abstract class CaliforniaWaterDataVisualizationJSPCode {
    static public void update(HttpServletRequest request, JspWriter out) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try(Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:California_Water_Data.db")) { 
            if(request.getParameter("caldata-surface-toxic") != null) {
                URL url = new URL("https://data.ca.gov/sites/default/files/Surface_Water_Toxicity_2001_2015.txt");
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                try(InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
                    byte[] data = new byte[urlConnection.getContentLength()];
                    inputStream.read(data);
                    String content = new String(data);
                    PSVParser.parseFile(content);
                }
            }
            out.println("Finished retrieving data from data.ca.gov's 2001 to 2015 surface water toxicity record<br>");
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            out.println("Error: <br>" + e + "<br><br>" + "Stack trace: <br>");
            for(StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace()) {
                out.println(element + "<br>");
            }
            out.println("<br>Cause: <br>" + e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Java EE 7 update 21. I am using SQLite JDBC 3.7.2's compiled and source JARs (sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar and sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2-sources.jar) from [java2s.com](http://java2s.com) running on GlassFish 4.1.1 build 1. You can access my code on GitHub at [github.com/dhDZsG9QfQK3VTiF5KOs/California_Water_Data_Visualization](https://github.com/dhDZsG9QfQK3VTiF5KOs/California_Water_Data_Visualization). I have created a GitHub issue about this at [github.com/dhDZsG9QfQK3VTiF5KOs/California_Water_Data_Visualization/issues/1](https://github.com/dhDZsG9QfQK3VTiF5KOs/California_Water_Data_Visualization/issues/1).

Stack trace:

```
org.sqlite.NestedDB$CausedSQLException.fillInStackTrace(NestedDB.java:649)
java.lang.Throwable.(Throwable.java:250)
java.lang.Exception.(Exception.java:54)
java.sql.SQLException.(SQLException.java:140)
org.sqlite.NestedDB$CausedSQLException.(NestedDB.java:626)
org.sqlite.NestedDB._open(NestedDB.java:63)
org.sqlite.DB.open(DB.java:86)
org.sqlite.Conn.open(Conn.java:140)
org.sqlite.Conn.(Conn.java:57)
org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:77)
org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
com.solly.CaliforniaWaterDataVisualizationJSPCode.update(CaliforniaWaterDataVisualizationJSPCode.java:18)
org.apache.jsp.update_jsp._jspService(update_jsp.java:53)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:323)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:321)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:356)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:214)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1676)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Are there any "caused by sections" in the stack trace? Is that the COMPLETE stack trace?

Comment: I think so. When I did printStackTrace, it didn't show any "caused by" sections in the console.

Comment: Remove all the code in your catch block and replace it with `e.printStackTrace();`  Then update your post with the "real" stack trace.

Comment: I do it like this so I can see it in the webpage. Also, the stack trace is the same

Comment: Since it's happening in `DriverManager.getConnection()` I don't see any options other than stepping into the SQLite code to see what's null.  Are you sure your connection string is valid and the DB file exists and can be found by the driver manager?

Comment: I thought it should auto-create the database if it doesn't exist

Comment: Can it create the database in the current directory?  It's probably trying and failing.

Comment: It *is* in the current directory (California_Water_Data.db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `DriverManager.registerDriver(new JDBC());` before the `try` block. What inspired me was the new error message (after restarting the server): "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:California_Water_Data.db".